# Add select value in form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, formbuilder

I have this Symfony form, it displays the values of the entity '*Manifestation*' that has a many to many relationship.

So I do: `->add('manifestations')`.

But when I try to add an empty_value 'All' in the select list, it doesn't work!

Can any one help me ? Thanks

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrifProtocoleBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_value' => 'All',
                'required' => false,));
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean about custom value, and how it behaves?

Comment: What do you mean "custom value", the one that is not in the database? How do you expect it to work then?

Comment: If you want to add new manifestation, you need to embed a manifestation form inside this form.

Comment: @Uriziel. yes that's right, actually the name of this value is 'choose all' it alouds the user to choose all the other options. but how to display this 'choose all' option in the select form?

Comment: @Piotr Pasich sorry didn't explain it well. the problem is that the 'empty_value'=> 'choose' is not displaying in the select form my question is how to display it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**empty values** New in Symfony version 2.3 .

**empty values** are also supported if the **expanded option** is set to **true**  like [Symfony 2.3 Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#empty-value)

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrifProtocoleBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,  
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_value' => 'All',
                'required' => false,));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and link. it helped me.finally i did this: multiple' => false, 'expanded' => false, so i get a select tag showing only the 'empty_value' which is now 'choose', so when i click on the arrow next to it, i have a drop down list with all the values.